# RowReaderFactory vs mapToPair (efficiency)

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I'm wondering what is the more efficient between RowReaderFactory and mapToPair in Spark.

## 1st method : mapToPair

```
JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Dog> dogPairRDD = functions.cassandraTable(keyspace, "dog")
    .mapToPair(new PairFunction<CassandraRow, PartitionKey, Dog>() {
        public Tuple2<PartitionKey, Dog> call(CassandraRow row) throws Exception {
            PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKey(row.getString("string1"), row.getString("string2"));
            Dog dog = new Dog("name","color");
            return new Tuple2<PartitionKey, Dog>(partitionKey, dog);
        }
    });
```

## 2nd method : RowReaderFactory

```
RowReaderFactory<Dog> dogRRF = new RowReaderDogFactory(); // implements RowReaderFactory<Dog>

JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Dog> dogPairRDD = functions.cassandraTable(keyspace, "dog", partitionKeyRRF, dogRRF);
```

Thanks in advance :)